# ID query string parameter call to RestResource results in error

Tags: apex, rest, apexrest, restresource, httppost

I'm looking to set up a RestResource endpoint that accepts some URL parameters and creates a lead record.
Here's the basic gist of my code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/createLead/*')
global with sharing class CreateLeadRest{
 @HttpPost
 global static void doPost() {   

   string id = RestContext.request.params.get('id');
   Lead newLead = new Lead();
   newLead.Company='test';
   newLead.LastName='test';
   newLead.Description=id;
   insert newLead;
   }
}
```

When I call this endpoint, I get this error:

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, invalid parameter value: []

Interestingly enough, if I create a new record of any object other than Lead or Case, the code works fine. But specifically for leads and cases, it doesn't like the ID parameter in the query string.

Anyone experience this?

Comment: what if you change id parameter to something like leadId or caseId ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava That would work well, but unfortunately, I'm setting this up as a webhook from a third-party system, so I have no control over the name of the ID parameter.

Comment: Sounds like an SFDC bug to me .What happens if you comment newLead.Description=id;

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Same result.

Comment: Can you try like this string Leadid = RestContext.request.params.get('id');

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I've tried with different variable names, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Is your 3rd party system putting the Id in the request body, or in the query string? POSTing with a query string is pretty uncommon, but I don't think there's anything in HTTP preventing people from doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

I was also able to make your `HttpPost` method work by moving the creation to a `@future` method.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/createLead/*')
global with sharing class CreateLeadRest{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost()
    {
        insertLead(RestContext.request.params.get('id'));
    }
    @future
    public static void insertLead(String id)
    {
        Lead newLead = new Lead();
        newLead.Company='test';
        newLead.LastName='test';
        newLead.Description=id;
        insert newLead;
    }
}
```

If you have conflicting `@future` calls getting in the way, consider using a `Queueable` implementation. You probably should develop a defensive asynchronous framework if you plan on executing asynchronous logic directly in your triggers. I know Dan Appleman has written a lot of material on the subject, and how to properly use an asynchronous framework is somewhat outside the scope of this question.

---

**Original Answer**

First of all, you should also look at this `Stack Overflow` post: **[How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)** URI parameters and `POST` requests are *fundamentally incompatible*.

Instead, you should shoot for a pattern more similar to how the documentation lays out `POST` requests in **[Creating REST APIs using Apex REST (Using POST, PUT and PATCH)](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST#Using_POST.2C_PUT_and_PATCH)**.

The way you would normally access `POST` parameters via `Apex REST` is more like:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/createLead/*')
global with sharing class CreateLeadRest{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(String id) {   
        Lead newLead = new Lead();
        newLead.Company='test';
        newLead.LastName='test';
        newLead.Description=id;
        insert newLead;
    }
}
```

Then if you pass the parameters through the **Body**, your request should **succeed**:

**Summary**

```
Method: POST
Endpoint: /services/apexrest/createLead/
Payload: {"id": 123}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Method:POST;Endpoint:/services/apexrest/createLead/;Payload:{"id":123}]

Whereas any attempt to pass parameters via the **URI** should **fail**:

**Summary**

```
Method: POST
Endpoint: /services/apexrest/createLead/?id=123
Payload: {"id": 123}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Method:POST;Endpoint:/services/apexrest/createLead/?id=123;Payload:{"id":123}]

Comment: Thanks for this @AdrianLarson. I do understand that you would not normally pass URL parameters for POST requests, but I am unfortunately at the mercy of the third-party provider in that regard. The provider allows for specifying a URL to which a webhook POST request will be passed, and the ID in question is not in the body of the request but in a URL parameter.

Comment: @emroc Then it cannot be a `POST` request. The two are incompatible. See also: [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) If they insist on sending you request parameters via the URI then you should insist on using a different vendor, because they don't understand how HTTP requests work.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I'm trying to find a workaround for this, and the only one I can think of is to call off to the SF REST API inside of my RestResource class to create the lead, instead of doing it directly in the class itself.

Comment: You could abuse `GET` to pass parameters via the URI, but it sounds like whoever you're working with is not very flexible.

Comment: Their API sends a POST request specifically, so doing a GET instead is simply not possible. What I find interesting is that this is only a problem if I attempt to create a lead or a case in the class. Any other object works fine. I'm guessing that this has something to do with SF web-to-lead/web-to-case, but that's just an assumption.

Comment: It's hard to believe they are so committed to doing HTTP Requests in a fundamentally incorrect way. I'm not sure why they ever work that way in `Apex REST`. They shouldn't, really. I guess Salesforce is just being more flexible than they have to be in some cases.

Comment: @AdrianLarson are you sure that POST requests can't have parameters in the query string portion of the URI? [This answer on another StackOverflow question suggests this is possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10426554/901352). What happens when you POST with a query string, leave the request body empty, remove the parameter from the POST method, and debug the request params?

Comment: @AdrianLarson The Future method is an interesting approach and would be the solution in any other circumstance, but I unfortunately have a trigger on Lead that calls off to another future method, so this seems to be a no-go for me.

Comment: @emroc Can you use a `Queueable` here then? Your trigger framework should probably be updated if this issue is preventing development, but using `Queueable` might at least get you a quick fix.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Good call, I've got it working well now. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're getting this error, is that Lead has required field LastName.

It seems that tool you're using is not providing full info, I would recommend to use Chrome extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). That will give HTTP 500 and:

> [
>     {
>       "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
>       "message": "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [LastName]: [LastName]\n\nClass.CreateLeadRest.doPost: line 12, column 1"
>     }
>   ]

or you can add to your code something like:

```
url: https://naxx.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/createLead?id=50036000000xxxx

global static String doPost() { 
//..
try {
    insert newLead;
} catch (exception e){
    return e.getMessage();
}

return newLead.id;
```

Comment: Sorry @IlyaLepesh, the code I provided doesn't have last name but my actual code does. I've run the code in an anonymous apex window and can confirm that it does indeed create the lead as expected. I've updated my original question.

Comment: @emroc, is it working now? How do you execute this from anonymous window?

Comment: it isn't working, no. I meant to say that my original code does include the last name, I just forgot to include it in the original question. If I just run the lead creation bit in an anonymous window, a lead gets created, but the same code doesn't create a lead in the RestResource class.

Comment: You code works fine, how are you reaching RestResource class?

Comment: Just with a simple post request. I've been using Postman in Chrome for testing.

Comment: @emroc, sounds like you're to calling to specific instance, which doesn't work.
Can you: a) Create new class CreateLeadRestv2 with mapping createLeadv2 b) Make sure it has api v35 or 36 c) During call, open debug log, it migth show something.

Comment: the class is using API version 37.0. And I am calling the RestResource class behind a Force.com sites setup, so I am not calling the Salesforce instance specifically: https://mydomain.cs2.force.com/mysitename/services/apexrest/createLead?id=12345

Comment: You are sending invalid id, try to send 001000000abcdef. or change to description: createLead?Description=12345, RestContext.request.params.get('Description'); It seems that id is reserved parameter and shoud be 15 lenght long

Comment: The ID I'm sending is actually not a Salesforce record ID, it's a completely separate ID from the third-party system. The issue is that Salesforce seems to be looking at that ID and expecting it to be a record ID.